# How to get VelocityEngine from Struts 2 jars

Tags: struts2, velocity

I'm trying to write a dynamic mailing system for a Struts2 based webapp.

I'd like to use velocity as templating tool and i was wondering if i can use the velocity bundled with Struts 2 or I need to get an independent copy of velocity JAR ?

So far i've tried this

```
VelocityManager vm = new VelocityManager();
VelocityEngine ve = vm.getVelocityEngine();
```

but eclipse complains abount missing VelocityEngine class with this error:

```
The method getVelocityEngine() from the type VelocityManager refers to the missing type VelocityEngine
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The class `VelocityEngine` is packed in `velocity-1.6.4.jar`. You should add this file to build path.

If you are using Maven then it should resolve dependency automatically.

Struts2 has support for using [velocity](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/velocity) as a template processor. You should read the docs how to use [velocity result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/velocity-result).

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's clear to me that struts uses velocity only as result template processor which is not my goal.
Including Velocity dependecy will not conflict with struts' bundled one ?

Comment: No, it uses jsp, fremarker, and velocity. It is already bundled and should resolve from `struts2-core`. See dependency tree.

Comment: yeah that's right, but eclipse doesn't let me include velocity from struts2 packages although i can see the VelocityEngine.class file.

Comment: do you have some problem with eclipse configuring  build path?